# eliminar el tercer input de mi código en python, al hacerlo y buscar una palabra que no tengo en mi lista se vuelve infinito el while

Tags: python, while, input

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi codigo necesito que solo pregunte una vez la palabra a buscar, por error la puse dos veces.

```
archivo_nombre=str(input('introduzca el nombre del archivo, no olvide poner el .txt al final ejemplo "archivo.txt" : '))
with open(archivo_nombre,'r',encoding='utf8')as ar:#abrimos el archivo en modo read
    archivo= ar.read()
print(archivo) #imprimimos el archivo 
l_text = archivo.split()#aplicamos el metodo split para guardar el texto del archivo en una lista llamada l_text
#print(l_text)# imprimimos la lista
n_palabras = len(l_text)#tenemos la cantidad de palabras de la lista
print(n_palabras)#imprime la cantidad de palabras en la lista
p_buscar = (input('que palabra quiere buscar: ')) #el usuario busca una palabras de la lista 
cantidad_palabra_buscada =l_text.count(p_buscar)#cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra buscada
print('la canridad de veces que aparece la palabra buscada es: ',cantidad_palabra_buscada) #imprimimos la cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra buscada 

while  p_buscar.startswith('fin') or cantidad_palabra_buscada == 0 : # mientras la cantidad de palabras buscadas sea igual a 0 va a ejecutar 
    p_buscar = (input('la palabra no existe busque de nuevo: ')) # este es el input que quiero eliminar
    cantidad_palabra_buscada =l_text.count(p_buscar) #da la cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra buscada en el texto
    print('la cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra buscada es: ',cantidad_palabra_buscada) #imprime la cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra en el texto
    if p_buscar.startswith('fin'):
        opcion= int(input('ingrese 1 para finalizar o 2 para buscar la palabra fin')) #el usuario introduce una opcion 
        if opcion==1:# si es igual a 1 
            print('gracias por ejecutar el programa') #imprime este mensaje 
            break
        else:# si no 
            print('la cantidad de veces que aparece fin en el texto es: ',cantidad_palabra_buscada)# imprime la cantidad de veces que aparece fin en el texto
```

el problema radica en que al eliminar el segundo input que pide buscar una palabra y buscar una que no esté en la lista, el ciclo se vuelve infinito. No sé cuál es mi error.

agrego la fraccion del codigo entero que está arriba, para señalar en donde quiero eliminar el input

```
 while  p_buscar.startswith('fin') or cantidad_palabra_buscada == 0 : # mientras la cantidad de palabras buscadas sea igual a 0 va a ejecutar 
        p_buscar = (input('la palabra no existe busque de nuevo: ')) # este es el input que quiero eliminar
```

Comment: y que pasa si `p_buscar ` no es `fin` ??

Comment: @Christian si es una palabra que está en la lista, muestra la cantidad de veces que se repite esa palabra y para. si es una desconocida el while se hace infinito

Comment: me refiero a la que está dentro del `while` y por eso mismo te faltaría un `else`